# n-sphere and the Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{S}^n$ be the $n-$sphere. Is $\mathbb{S}^n-\{(0,0,\dots,1)\}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

If so, I would like to find the explicit homeomorphisim between them. Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: Google "stereographic projection."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard homeomorphism is given by [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perfectly clear now.